# Highcharts yaxis max

Tags: highcharts

I have a script which uses HighCharts. Below is the yAxis part of the script that deal with the formation of said yAxis. Where I have "yAxis:max I am trying to use a PHP variable produced by a query.

I know the PHP variable "$row_Rooms['Rooms']" contains "400", but when I run the script the yAxis max displays "420".

```
$(function () {

var categories=[];
var data2 =[];


var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("temp_hot_chart.php", function(json) { 
        $.each(json,function(i,el) { 
        if (el.name=="Count") 
        categories = el.data; 
        else data2.push(el); 
        }); 



        $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginTop: 60,
                marginRight: 30,
                marginBottom: 90,
                plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Failed hot water temperatures',
                x: -20, //center
                style: {
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '11px'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
             xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                max:<?php echo $row_Rooms['Rooms'];?>,
                reversedStacks: false, 
                showFirstLabel: false,
                lineColor:'#999',
                lineWidth:1,
                tickColor:'#666',
                tickWidth:1,
                tickLength:2,
                tickInterval: 10,
                gridLineColor:'#ddd',
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    style: {
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '12px'
                }
                },
                plotLines: [{

                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },

                 legend: {
                    enabled: true
                 },




                colors: [
                '#0066CC', 
                '#FF2F2F', 
                ],

                plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    legendIndex:0,
                    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    //rotation: -90,
                    color: '#000000',
                    align: 'center',
                    //format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                    y: 20, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                }

            },




            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },


            series: data2
        });
    });

});
```

});

Can anyone throw any light on to why this is happening. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Regards.

Comment: Try setting the endOnTick value to false as its default is true and that can effect the max value. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max

Comment: Hi Todd, Reading the HighCharts documents Max is auto rounded so I don't think that I can do what I need. But many hnaks for your reply.

Comment: Did you try Todd's solution?

Comment: DCJones yes, the max is rounded to fit the tickInterval. But if you use @Todd s solution, that is overridden. There are a number of ways to get what you need on the yAxis, including using endOnTick: false, setting the tickInterval in a way that matches what you need your max to be, using the tickPositions property, etc.

Comment: Set [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) as 0. If it will not solve your problem, use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner) to return ticks in particular places.

Answer (score 1):

use endOnTick and set it to false, 
as in described in the documentation http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max

> If the endOnTick option is true, the max value might be rounded up

Please check the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/8LwaLra9/):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            endOnTick: false,
            max:101,
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add **alignTicks: false** to the chart block:

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false
    }
```

Hope it helps